# Scrolling with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Ok, so here's the situation, I have a div with horizontal scrolling, the structure looks like this.

```
<div class="extra-holder">
    <div class="extra-holder-inner">
        <ul>
            <li>Stuff here</li>
            <li>Stuff here</li>
            <li>Stuff here</li>
            <li>Stuff here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the content is dynamic inside the ul, so fixed widths are out.

I'm using the fantastic jquery mousewheel plugin to make scrolling within the div scroll horizontal instead of vertically, works absolutely fine.

The problem arises when trying to scroll on a touch screen, you can't scroll at all.

So, my naive solution was to just have two buttons and animate the inner container, extra-holder-inner, left/right.

Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#scroll-r').click(function() {
  $('.extra-holder-inner').animate({

    left: '-=341' //animating by the width of the li's within the container
  }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#scroll-l').click(function() {
  $('.extra-holder-inner').animate({

    left: '+=341'
  }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
});
```

Now the problem with this is really two fold, it's animating the container left/right instead of scrolling it AND the user can animate left when there's no other items to the left, it's a useless solution.

So either I need to do something a heck of a lot more complex or I need to figure out a way to have those buttons scroll left/right by 341px instead of animating the container.

Ideas, thoughts?

Comment: You can use Touch-scroll plugin and here is question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573715/touch-scroll-jquery-plugin-how-to-init-with-different-options-for-multiple-ins

Comment: no longer exists on github.

Comment: But the code is in the answer.